# sed not matching wildcards greedily to crop string parts

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have this string

```
extension_dir => /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303 => /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value
```

which is the output of `php -i | grep extension_dir`.

How can I parse it in bash to get the first `/some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303`?

So far I have tried:

`echo $(php -i | grep extension_dir | sed 's/extension_dir => //g' | sed 's/=> .*//g')`

but that gives me `/some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303  sqlite3.no value`. I have no idea why it doesn't replace all matches of `=> .*`

My base idea is to get rid of first `extension_dir =>` and than rid of everything after first `=>` including `=>` Probably sed matches things differently than regex.

Comment: What is the exact output you want?  It looks like it's done just what you described: all matches of `=> .*` have been removed.

Comment: There are two ouput lines instead of one and therefore sed doesn't work. I wanted to get `/some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
php -i | sed -n '/extension_dir/{s/^[^/]*//;s/ *=>.*$//;p;}'
```

or, as suggested in comments below,

```
php -i | sed '/extension_dir/!d;s/[^/]*//;s/ *=>.*//'
```

The `sed` above replaces your `grep` and will, for every line that matches `extensions_dir`, first remove everything up to the first `/` and then everything from the first `=>` onwards in the *modified* string.  Any spaces before the `=>` are also removed. Lines not matching `extensions_dir` are ignored.

This will return the wanted path for the first line of input, and an empty line for the second.

To disregard the second line of input, use `/^extension_dir/` instead of `/extension_dir/` in the `sed` above. This will discard the second line since does not start with that string.

---

It's the combination of your two `sed` scripts that produces the surprising result for the second line of input.

The line is

```
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value
```

and the first `sed` will modify this to

```
sqlite3.no value => no value
```

The second `sed` will then remove the `=> no value` bit at the end.

---

Note that

```
echo $( ... )
```

is a bit useless as it gobbles up the newlines in the output of the command inside `$( ... )`.  Instead test with just the command without the `echo` or the `$( ... )` command substitution.

It is possibly this use of `echo` that has had you confused about the nature of the output from `php -i` and `grep` (two matching lines rather than one).

Comment: Shorter, and IMHO easier to read by deleting the inverted match instead of `-n` and `{...;p}`. And the anchors `^` and `$` seem superfluous in this case, so `sed '/extension_dir/!d;s/[^/]*//;s/ *=>.*//'` would do the same job.

Comment: @Kusalananda I was thinking that `sqlite3.no value` would be taken away with matching the first `=>` in `=> /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303 sqlite3.no value => no value`. So this would have been matched `=> /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303 sqlite3.no value`. Why was only `=> /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303` matched?

Comment: @simPod Because `sed` processes its input data line by line, and you have two separate lines of input.

Comment: Thanks for more detailed explaination of my `sed` use

Comment: @Philippos: Well, in ***my*** humble opinion, “process the lines that match this pattern” is clearer than “process all lines except for the ones that *don’t* match this pattern” (double negative).  But I suppose some people may be confused by ``-n`` and `p`.

Answer (score 8):

I can give you a simple awk solution.

```
php -i | awk -F ' => ' '/extension_dir/{print $2; exit}'
```

That will work if you want to lose the sed.

EDIT: Moved exit to inside the block to avoid a syntax error, added spaces around field separator so they won't be output with the resulting filepath, and describe change in body, so stackexchange allows the edit due to minimum character change limitation.

Comment: Very simple, thanks! I might probably use this one. However, marked Kusalananda's aswer as accepted as it explains the sed problem and that was the original question.

Comment: Yes, awk is a much better choice for columnar data such as this - exactly the answer I thought of when I read the question.

Answer (score 2):

If path doesn't contain spaces, this expression will be enough:

```
php -i | grep -Po 'extension_dir => \K/[^ ]*'
```

**Input**

```
extension_dir => /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303 => /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value
```

**Output**

```
/some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
```